# How to remove duplicated Applications folders? Menu editor doesn't work with these

Tags: menu, appmenu

[image: Screenshot]

Couldn't not find a way to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I ended up dragging out manually the applications from the four duplicated folders, and that removed them all.